# How to test AjaxEventBehavior("onClick") for Apache Wicket radio button?

Tags: ajax, testing, wicket

I'm using apache wicket and I run into trouble regarding testing the AjaxEventBehavior for a Radio button. Actually I want to test the "onClick" event like in my case when I select/click a radio button from a RadioGroup a specif page is rendered.

Code snippet:

```
RadioGroup<Boolean> selectPageRadioGroup =
        new RadioGroup<Boolean>("selectPageRadioGroup", new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE));
selectPageRadioGroup.setDefaultModel(new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE));
final Radio<Boolean> radioButton1 =
        new Radio<Boolean>("radioButton1", new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.FALSE));
radioButton1.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {
    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        setResponsePage(MyWebPage.class);
    }
});
selectPageRadioGroup.add(radioButton1);
```

Comment: A code snippet would certainly help.

Comment: @Don<html><code>RadioGroup<Boolean> selectPageRadioGroup = new RadioGroup<Boolean>("selectPageRadioGroup",                                                                     new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE));      selectPageRadioGroup.setDefaultModel(new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE));final Radio<Boolean> radioButton1 = new Radio<Boolean>("radioButton1",new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.FALSE));    radioButton1.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") { @Override protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {      setResponsePage(MyWebPage.class);}});    selectPageRadioGroup.add(radioButton1);</code>

Comment: @DonRoby Sorry there is some problem with pasting code with nice format here. I'm new on this website.  Thanks!

Comment: You can't add formatted code in comments. I edited your post to add your snippet. My edit will be visible when peer-reviewed

Comment: You should also add your testing code. Without it, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks @bernie. I could not figure out How To Test "onClick" event for the radio button and that is what I need help for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have already done

```
WicketTester tester = new WicketTester();
tester.startPage(PageContainingRadioButton.class);
```

or a similar `startPanel` (Wicket 1.4) or `startComponent` (Wicket 1.5), so that your test has rendered a page containing the button at a known path you should be able to make WicketTester simulate the ajax behavior by something like

```
tester.executeAjaxEvent("blabla:form:selectPageRadioGroup:radioButton1", "onclick");
```

(You'll need to adjust that path of course.)

and then check that it did the right thing with

```
tester.assertRenderedPage(MyWebPage.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I made little change tester.executeAjaxEvent and it works with me. Unfortunately I don't have have enough reputations to vote for you. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  You probably can accept the answer (you should see a check that you can click.  And then you and I will both gain some rep.  And you're right - it should be executeAjaxEvent for this.  I'll fix the answer.