# How to test appended javascript on wicket ajaxBehavior on JUnit test?

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, junit, wicket

I have a function that appends in onload() method some javascript to the AjaxRequestTarget.

I load it by

```
add(onload);
```

and onload is having code like

```
AjaxEventBehavior event = new AjaxEventBehavior("onload") {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            attachJavascriptBehavior(target);
        }
    };
    return event;
```

attachJavascriptBehavior adds some javascript as text to the target.

I want to test it with WicketTester.

So far I know I can make calls like:

```
tester.executeAjaxEvent("some:path", "onclick");
```

and maybe same will apply somehow for the onload, too. I found I can then call

```
tester.assertRenderedPage(MyWebPage.class);
```

to test if page is rendered after the event (event tackles some content size), but even if I in browser get errors in console, this tests goes surprisingly through. How to catch that console.log has reported javascript errors?

Source:

[How to test AjaxEventBehavior("onClick") for Apache Wicket radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415330/how-to-test-ajaxeventbehavioronclick-for-apache-wicket-radio-button)

Comment: Tested, not catching my error: tester.assertNoErrorMessage();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as general tip, you can access to the last response with

```
String responseTxt = tester.getLastResponse().getDocument();
```

then you can check what has been returned to client.

Comment: Right. You need to work with the last response as a String because an Ajax call doesn't repaint the whole page. Usually Ajax response returns the new markup only for part(s) of the page.

Comment: This gives something and is kinda right solution. Mine just did not give here anything useful, because last page has a waiting icon scrolling on the place of data, when I take the document. Maybe a timer to wait some seconds would help, or I bypass this test as impossible.

Comment: Adding timeout of 10 sec did not change anything.

Comment: This way I could see what ajax was loading from server, ajax event target changes for the css and layout related changes I could not track. This is the closest and I accept it, because there aren't closer guesses.